# Regex to capture entire string in python panda series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a sample series:

```
s = pd.Series(['Complexity Level 1', 'RandomName', 'I-Invoice Submission test', 'I-test2', 'I-string with multiple words'])
```

I'm trying to capture only strings that begin with "I-". Using `extract`.

```
extract1 = s.str.extract(r'I-(\w+)')
```

Current Output:

```
    0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   Invoice
3   test2
4   string
```

It's currently only extracting the first word. But I want all words and white space after the identifier. This could be up to 5 words

Is this a regex adjustment or is there a better method?

What I want is:

```
    0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   Invoice Submission test
3   test2
4   string with multiple words
```

Comment: Added my initial comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex that will do the job is `r'I-(.*)'`?. Meaning: capture any character (until a newline) after `"|-"`.

---

**EDIT** (From comments):

To capture any character up until a comma use `I-([^,]*)`. Meaning: capture any character that is not a comma (`,`) after `"|-"`.

Comment: how can I limit capture until comma?